# Perform logical OR operation on multiple NumPy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code:

```
array1 = np.array([1,0,1,0])
array2 = np.array([1,1,0,0])

array3 = array1 | array2
```

array3 will be:

```
[1 1 1 0]
```

This code works fine but I would like to extend it to more arrays without writing out `array1 | array2 | array3 | etc`.

Anyone know an efficient way of doing this? Possibly using .any()?

Comment: I don't know how it's done in Python, but the concept is known as "fold", "reduce" or "accumulate". Look for similar functions in the python std.

Comment: Haha googling is much easier when you know the term! Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would stick to NumPy here, but there are a few ways of doing it. Here's using `logical_or.reduce`.

```
np.logical_or.reduce([array1, array2])
# array([ True,  True,  True, False])
```

---

Another variant is using  using `column_stack` and `any`:

```
np.column_stack([array1, array2]).any(axis=1)
# array([ True,  True,  True, False])
```

Comment: I am thinking about `np.any([array1,array2],axis=0)` may work here?

Comment: @Wen-Ben Yup. But `any` still has to convert the list `[array1,array2]` into a new array. It is about the same as column_stack, maybe slightly faster... perhaps we might learn more from the timings :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use `reduce` with the `operator.or_`:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

reduce(operator.or_, [array1, array2])
# array([1, 1, 1, 0])
```

Note that in Python 3, [`reduce` was moved](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) to the `functools` library, but in Python 2, it's a built-in.

Comment: I went for the other answer as I'm working in numpy. Your solution looks good too though and I'll bare it in mind next time I'm not using np!

Answer (score 3):

Since you tag `pandas` one way of using `any` for `|` , if you need `&` try with `all`

```
pd.DataFrame([array1,array2]).any(1).values
```

Comment: Oh wow. I was actually asking in order to incorporate this into something I'm doing in pandas so this is great. Thank you!

Comment: @HenryDashwood ha , happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also sum up the two arrays. If either of the elements is 1, the sum will be 1. If both are 1, the sum will be 2 in which case you reassign the value of 1 using `np.where` as

```
array3 = np.where(array1+array2==2, 1, array1+array2)
# array([1, 1, 1, 0])
```